# Limit of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Suppose $T_n$ is a sequence of self-adjoint bounded operators on a Hilbert space, and $T_n \rightarrow T$ in operator norm, $T$ being also bounded and self-adjoint.
Do we then have: $T_n^m\rightarrow T^m$ for every integer $m>0$?

I believe this is true if $T_n$ and $T$ commute, since then we can easily factor through $||T_n-T||$, but in the non-commutative case I'm not sure how to prove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Operator multiplication is continuous in operator norm.  To see this (if you haven't already), suppose $S_n \to S$ and $T_n \to T$.  In particular, $\sup_n \|T_n\| < \infty$.  Then
$$\|S_n T_n - ST\| \le \|S_n T_n - S_n T\| + \|S_n T - ST\| \le \|S_n\| \|T_n - T\| + \|S_n - S\| \|T\|$$
and both terms go to 0.

Now to show your claim, use induction on $m$.

Note that self-adjointness is not needed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n:=T_n-T$. Write 
$$T_n^p-T_n^p=(T+A_n)^p-T^p=\sum_{\substack{J\subset [p]\\J\neq \emptyset}}P_J,$$
where $P_J$ is a product of $p$ operators $B_1\dots B_p$, for which $B_j=A_n$ if $j\in J$ and $B_j=T$ otherwise. This gives 
$$\lVert T_n^p-T^p\rVert\leqslant \sum_{\substack{J\subset [p]\\J\neq \emptyset}}\lVert A_n\rVert^{|J|}\lVert T\rVert^{p-|J|}=(\lVert A_n\rVert+\lVert T\rVert)^p-\lVert T\rVert^p\to 0.$$